# Linux cluster, Rmpi and number of procesess

Tags: r, linux, bash, mpi, cluster-computing

Since the beginning of November, I'm stuck in to run a parallel job in a Linux cluster. I already search A LOT on the internet searching for information but I simply can't progress. When I start to search for parallelism in R using cluster I discovered the Rmpi. It looked quite simple, but now I don't now more what to do. I have a script to send my job:

```
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -N ANN_residencial
#PBS -q linux.q
#PBS -l nodes=8:ppn=8

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

source /hpc/modulos/bash/R-3.3.0.sh

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/hpc/nlopt-2.4.2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CPPFLAGS='-I/hpc/nlopt-2.4.2/include '$CPPFLAGS
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/hpc/nlopt-2.4.2/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH

# OPENMPI 1.10 + GCC 5.3
source /hpc/modulos/bash/openmpi-1.10-gcc53.sh
mpiexec --mca orte_base_help_aggregate 0 -np 1 -hostfile ${PBS_NODEFILE} /hpc/R-3.3.0/bin/R --slave -f sunhpc_mpi.r
```

And this is the beginning of my R program:

```
library(caret)
library(Rmpi)
library(doMPI)

cl <- startMPIcluster()
registerDoMPI(cl)
```

So here is my questions:

1- Is this way I should initialize the processes (i.e. using starMPIcluster whitout a parameter and using at the command line -np 1)?

2- Why when I use this commands the MPI complains with it's frase?

```
An MPI process has executed an operation involving a call to the
"fork()" system call to create a child process....
```

OBS: He said that for all the 64 processes (because there are 8 nodes with 8 cpus and I'm creating 63 processes)

3- Why when I use this commands on a machine of 60 CPU's he just spawn two workers?

Comment: I have never managed to get an `R` cluster properly working with `MPI`. I am really not someone who gives up easily, but, in the end, I went back to using `PSOCK` clusters... Hope that someone on SO can give you more encouraging news.

Comment: did you try `cl <- startMPIcluster(count=63)`?

Comment: Actually, not. You don't have to pass a parameter on this function. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it!

To run a parallel program in R using the Rmpi in a cluster you need to configure the job script according to the system. Next on the command line:

```
mpiexec --mca orte_base_help_aggregate 0 -np 1 -hostfile ${PBS_NODEFILE} /hpc/R-3.3.0/bin/R --slave -f sunhpc_mpi.r
```

You have to modify to:

mpiexec -np NUM_PROC -hostfile ${PBS_NODEFILE} /hpc/R-3.3.0/bin/R --slave -f sunhpc_mpi.r

On the R code, you must not detail anything 'startMPIcluster()' So, the code will exactly as I wrote above.